# Time truncate with json operator postgresql rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, postgresql

I have model `integration` with associated model `integration_profiles` with a json column called `data`

Trying to query and group by the date with truncation.

```
i.integration_profiles.select("date_trunc('hour', timestamp data ->> 'created_at' )").group("data ->> 'created_at'")
```

Get this error:

```
PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "data"
LINE 1: SELECT date_trunc('hour', timestamp data ->> 'created_at' ) ...
```

Comment: I haven't seen these symbols `->>`.I guess you meant to use `=>`.

Comment: its for JSON data column